# Import and Edit *.MXD in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, mxd

Do you know of a way to enter a file directly from the MXD extension QGIS?
Is this possible?
How about MapPackage files?
I do not have access to the ArcMap software.
Best Regards.

Comment: Not possible yet, but a plugin is being developed: https://north-road.com/2019/02/04/announcing-our-slyr-funding-drive/

Comment: very expensive!!!!can I get this plugin free?@romainbh

Comment: I found this link in github ::          https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr@romainbh

Comment: MXD document conversion is currently under development. "Expected full implementation date: August 30, 2019...As described in Open Source Pledge, we will release the SLYR vector LYR conversion functionality under an open source license 6 months after reaching 30 additional project sponsors." So this feature will be available for free at some future date, as long as they get the required sponsorships.

Comment: Unfortunately, my account on this forum is limited by some really strange reasons and I can not say what I mean by inserting a better image.
My question is very clear. Can I import mxd file?
What is the Arcmap to Qgis tool?@csk@romainbh

Comment: And the response is very clear: unfortunately it is yet not possible to import MXD file in QGIS. You can wait for the future plugin from North Road or buy it to support the development.

Comment: You did not pay attention. I inserted link of SLYR plugin 2 days ago . link:https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr @csk

Comment: but not installed?? can You Test it? Thanks.@csk

Comment: CAN YOU ANSWER??? @romainbh

Comment: Don't yell, it's rude. Did you bother reading the README.md in the repo you linked to? "*This open-source version only supports ESRI .style database files. See https://north-road.com/slyr/ for the version which supports direct LYR file conversion. Otherwise, it is necessary to use ArcGIS to convert a .lyr file to a .style database prior to conversion with this version.*" So you can't use it to convert mxds.

Comment: @GIS_Esri please don't yell. I have answered your question: it's not possible yet. csk and user2856 have also replied and they say the same thing.

Comment: @romainbh please add an answer so I can vote it up and get this question off the unanswered list.

Comment: I apologize to you and I'm sorry. I ask again:
Is it possible to import MXD files and mappackages directly into QGIS software? I've already made layouts in arcmap and I've got it out and now I want to use QGIS software. After research, I came up with the following results:
1 Use the Purchased Plugins (SLYR) and not the free Nourth Road site
@user2856 @romainbh@csk

Comment: continue text::::2 Use the slyr plugin located on the github site with the following link:
https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr
3. Use the arcmap to qgis tool in arcmap software
Unfortunately, no one responds. You have a solution ????
Of course, strange thing is the number 2 of the results that I ask you to check it out.
Thank you for being responsive and tolerant @user2856@csk@romainbh

Comment: As we have already said, you cannot use the github code. It's only for .style files. Not for mxd, not for mpk, not for lyr files. There is currently no way to import an mxd to qgis. However, a map package mpk is a zip file so you can unzip it to extract the data from the .gdb. You won't be able to read any rasters though, just vector feature classes.

Answer (score 2):

**Importing MXD files into QGIS is not possible** because MXD is proprietary ESRI-only formats, with no public specifications allowing their use.

North Road is actually developping a QGIS plugin for converting MXD and LYR files into QGIS compatible format. They already have created a plugin - SLYR - to convert .style ESRI files to QGIS format, and they want to develop it more to make it compatible with MXD and LYR formats. [Please read this for more informations.](https://north-road.com/2019/02/04/announcing-our-slyr-funding-drive/)

If you own an ESRI licence, you can try to use the [arcgis2qgs toolbox](https://github.com/milieuinfo/arcgis2qgs) to convert MXD to QGS files.